# Reversing a type converter with minimal redundancies

Tags: c#, inheritance, composition

The objective is to implement the reversed version of `StringToDoubleConverter` but without writing too many redundancies. I love DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) design principle.

```csharp
public class StringToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return double.TryParse(value as string, out var x) ? x : double.NaN;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is double x ? x.ToString("f3") : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Here are my approaches. Any suggestions or comments are welcome.

### Version A: Inheritance

```csharp
public class DoubleToStringConverter : StringToDoubleConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public new object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return base.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
    public new object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return base.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
}
```

### Version B: Composition

```
public class DoubleToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly StringToDoubleConverter std = new();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return std.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return std.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized. I should choose the version B and make all classes `sealed`.

Comment: what is the `IValueConverter` definition?

Comment: Are you using this IValueConverter interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 ?

Comment: Btw why do you need two classes? Isn't your first class enough?

Comment: @PeterCsala `IValueConverter` is in your link. Two classes are needed for two different usages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you define an `abstract` class with the following two methods:

- One which can convert an `object` to `string`
- Another which can convert an `object` to `double`

```
public abstract class FromObjectConverter
{
    protected double ToDouble(object value)
        => double.TryParse(value as string, out var x) ? x : double.NaN;

    protected string ToString(object value)
        => value is double x ? x.ToString("f3") : string.Empty;
}
```

With this class in our hand the two concrete converter classes are just simple wrappers

```
public sealed class StringToDoubleConverter : FromObjectConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => ToDouble(value);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => ToString(value);
}

public sealed class DoubleToStringConverter : FromObjectConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => ToString(value);

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => ToDouble(value);
}
```

---

Or if you want to avoid inheritance then define the `FromObjectConverter` class and its methods as `static`.